# What does Delete project do in Visual Studio Team Services Git Repository Explorer?

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio Team Services repository explorer, the left panel lists all the projects in the selected Git repository. Hovering over a project name reveals a . . . button, and clicking that exposes some options, one of which is "Delete". (Right clicking the project name also exposes these options.)

What will actually happen if I click Delete? If I Delete a project from my Git repository in VSTS, then pull that remote branch back into my Visual Studio 2015 solution, will it delete that project from my local repository?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you delete a project, a folder or a file in VSTS as you've explained above, the files will be deleted from your local repo if you do a pull.